# Can fileupload be worked without the form (enctype) in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

If i take the `<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "uploadfile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {%> //input type file
<% } %>` then it
 works fine.
so, is there any other way of uploading file without the form tag.can we do this with jquery.
correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no you cannot do this.